# Can column level be put as horizontal in JMeter aggregate graph

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing

I wish to display the column levels(Refer to the attached Image)vertically in JMeter Aggregate Graph, I could'nt be able to find any option to this is from UI settings, User.properties & jmeter.Properties files.
Any help on this would be very much helpful.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJpqF.png)
I am using JMeter version 5.4.1

I wish to display the column levels(Refer to the attached Image)vertically in JMeter Aggregate Graph